# Shopify Collection Conditions - Possible to group conditions for AND OR rules?

Tags: shopify

apologies for asking this here but I Googled both the Internet and Shopify forums with no results.

Q. Is it possible to group conditions in the Shopify Collections? An example is below:

I have a product bread, with sub-menus for age. My menu is as follows:

**Bread**

- > Fresh
- > 1-3 days old
- > 4-6 days old

To prevent tagging (which we're doing already but it's not feasible and scalable due to the huge number of tags we need to handle), is it possible to have a condition list like this for Bread:

**- "Fresh Bread" menu**

- Product tag is equal to bread AND word "fresh" in title

**- "1-3 days Bread" menu**

- Product tag is equal to bread AND
- > "1 day old" word in the title OR
- > "2 day old" word in the title OR
- > "3 day old" word in the title OR

"4-6 days Bread" menu is the same as above but 4, 5 and 6 days old for words in title.

Thanks!

I've tried searching the internet for this, also looked into apps that claim they can do multiple grouping conditions (but these are paid with a monthly fee), and lastly am now taking a step to see if liquid coding can settle this (but prefer to just use the default Shopify menu features).